# How to Get Access Token and User Info: IdentityServer4 With AspNet Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, access-token

Good day everyone,

So I successfully integrated IdentityServer 4 using AspNet Identity for authentication  into my project. It redirects to the client after authentication, so thats fine. The problem now is that I would like to get the user details on the client, like their username, email, firstname and lastname. I wanted to call the userinfo endpoint with a token, but I cannot get a token. I get the following errors:

1. Client not authorized for client credentials flow, check the AllowedGrantTypes setting - When I use `GrantType.Authorization` Code in client config
2. client cannot request openid scopes in client credentials flow - When I use `GrantType.ClientCredentials`

The The client has been setup in startup.cs as;

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("cookie")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorityUrl"];
                options.ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.UsePkce = true;
                options.ResponseMode = "query";

                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.SaveTokens = true;

            });
```

And my client configuration currently is as follows;

```
new Client
                    {
                         ClientName = "Admin Client",
                         ClientId = "admin.client",
                         AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                         ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secretkey".Sha256()) },
                         AllowedScopes =new List<string> {
                               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                               IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                            },
                         RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44324/signin-oidc"},
                         FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44324/signout-oidc",
                         PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44324/signout-callback-oidc"},

                         AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                         RequirePkce = true,
                         RequireConsent = false,
                         AllowPlainTextPkce = false

                    }
```

To get token, I do this (when I use `GrantType.ClientCredentials` in Client config;

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = _discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"],
                Scope = "openid"

            });
```

And I call user like this:

```
var response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
            {
                Address = _discoveryDocument.UserInfoEndpoint,
                Token = token
            });
```

but it never gets to the userinfo though.
Please note that I have been changing the GrantTypes in the client config to Hybrid, AuhorizationCode, it still doesn't work. When I use AuthorizationCode grantType and Use `RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync`, it request for Code in the parameters, but I don't know how to get the authorization code (sorry, I'm new to this please).

So please how should I configure my client in order to be able to request token that I can use in the userinfo endpoint or is there any way I can get the user info?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: google on the word `claims`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user detail you use Claims

basically you call it like this

`@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value` (on cshtml page)

or

`User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "mail").First().Value` (on .cs class)